# Notation of register values 1'b0 and 2'b00

Tags: binary, terminology, datasheet

I've seen in a datasheet the notation 1'b0 and 2'b00 to refer to some register values. I assume that it is used to represent a value in binary, specifying the number of bits at the beginning, and its value at the end. Anyway, where is this notation used? Only in specification sheets,  or is there any language where you can specify values in this way? Is there a similar way to specify octal/decimal/hexadecimal values?

Comment: Looks like Verilog, but wouldn't you know better where you saw it than us?

Comment: I saw it in a datasheet, but wanted to know wheter it is used in any language or not @Amadan

Comment: "A datasheet" conveys almost no information about the context you saw it in.

Comment: It just referred to many registers, some of 1 bit depth and others of 2 bits. Their description was defining it's value for different settings (e.g. `register[1:0] = 2'b01` for using a filter or `register[1:0] = 2'b11` for another filter) @Amadan

Comment: I've been looking to [verilog notations](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/verilog_number_literals.pdf) and it seems this kind of nomenclature is used. Will keep searching whether there is another language using it too. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is used as an international standard and can be found more or less everywhere, with octal i'm not sure, with decimal you can as it is represented by Mantissa and Exponent as shown below:

---

15000 is also equal to
1.5E4

---

That is known as scientific notation

And lastly in Hexadecimal there is no shortened way
Hope this helps!